# Asterisk securing passwords

Tags: security, asterisk

I am running asterisk on the [raspberry pi 3](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/); therefore, I want to protect the passwords. Someone can remove the SD card and the passwords will be in plain text! I know I can encrypt the entire OS but it will be nice if I can avoid doing that since I just have to protect one file.

There are **3** types of keys/passwords I want to protect. So far I have managed to protect 2 passwords out of the tree.

Anyways here is my old `sip.conf` unprotected:

```
[general]

  keepalive=30
  bindport=5060
  ... etc

  ; Allow tls !    
  tlsenable=yes
  tlsbindaddr=0.0.0.0
  tlscertfile=/keys/asterisk.pem     ; <---- 1st key unprotected
  tlscafile=/keys/ca.crt
  tlscipher=ALL
  tlsclientmethod=tlsv1


; Peers info ---------------------------------------------
[user1]
  secret=somePassword       ; < -------- 2nd key unprotected
  type=peer
  ... etc

[user2]
  ... etc..   ; more  unprotected keys
; ----------------------------------------------------------

; elastic sip trunks used to make outbound calls -----------
[Trunk-Provider-1] ; 
  type=peer
  host=someProvider.com
  secret=plainTextPassword    ; <------------ 3rd password unprotected
  username=foo      
; ---------------------------------------------------------
```

And here is my new `sip.conf` "protected":

```
[general]

  keepalive=30
  bindport=5060
  ... etc

  ; Allow tls !       
  tlsenable=yes
  tlsbindaddr=0.0.0.0                      
  tlscertfile=/dev/shm/keys/asterisk.pem   ; <---- 1st key located on memory (/dev/shm/)
  tlscafile=/dev/shm/keys/ca.crt           ; same thing. File is on memory and NOT on disk. 
  tlscipher=ALL
  tlsclientmethod=tlsv1


; Peers info ---------------------------------------------
[user1]      
  md5secret=4a8e71480c5b1ef0a5d502a8eb98576  ; < -------- 2nd key hashed (protected)
  type=peer
  ... etc

[user2]
  ... etc..   ; more hashed keys
; ----------------------------------------------------------

; elastic sip trunks used to make outbound calls -----------
[Trunk-Provider-1] ; 
  type=peer
  host=omeProvider.com
  secret=password-Of-Provider  ; <------------ 3rd password I do not know how to protect this :/ ?
  username=foo
; ---------------------------------------------------------
```

So I have to protect 3 types of keys/passwords.

1. **Certificate Keys**
   The certificates used to encrypt calls. I protect that by downloading it when computer boots and placing them on memory (`/dev/shm/`). If the computer turns off the files will be lost.
2. **Ip Phones Passwords (peers)**
   This are the password used by phones (peers). In order to protect them I hash them. This article explains how that is done: https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sip+md5secret
3. **Provider's Passwords (used to make outbound calls)**
   I dont know how to protect this passwords. I thought about moving the location of my sip.conf file to memory but that is not eassy. That requires to move all configuration files I belive.

Comment: One solution may be to add the sip trunk dynamically? Is there a way I can add sip peers dynamically into asterisk without adding them to sip.conf?

Comment: Yes, you can use mysql realtime and in-memory table in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

I moved the file /etc/asterisk/sip.conf by creating a Symbolic link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1951752/637142

```
# 1. Delete /etc/asterisk/sip.conf we do not want that file on disk. It contains passwords!
rm /etc/asterisk/sip.conf

# 2. create sip.conf on memory (/dev/shm/sip.conf)
touch /dev/shm/sip.conf
... add configuration and passwords... to that file

# 3. Trick asterisk by placing a symbolic link. 
# Point file /etc/asterisk/sip.conf ---> /dev/shm/sip.conf
ln -s /dev/shm/sip.conf /etc/asterisk/sip.conf
```

No when I access /etc/asterisk/sip.conf in reality I am accessing /dev/shm/sip.conf!

Comment: What do you do when you lose power?